# Create my first iPhone application problem? Changing view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, window, viewcontroller

Hello I am trying to have to pages : Entry , and Gallery List ...

I can set `rootViewController` in window object. Within the Entry page, I have a button that will react and change to a new `GalleryViewController`.

Both I used to same code to set the `rootViewController` on window object. The later one I use the line below to get the window object

```
Photo_GalleryAppDelegate *delegate = (Photo_GalleryAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
```

and in both i used this line

```
GalleryListViewController *galleries = [[GalleryListViewController alloc] init];

[delegate.window setRootViewController: galleries];
```

The problem i have is: There is no error when button clicks and no visual changes the screen . It just stay on the same entry screen of my application .

Does anyone have any idea of what is going here?

In the `GalleryListViewControl` I just placed a `textfield` and a `label` to test whether i can go to that page.

Please Help

Comment: Assuming you're using IB, is the button connected to the appropriate IBAction method?

Comment: Can you post a bit more code?  We need more context to determine what is happening.

Comment: Yea I am using IB .. I have used the breakpoint to see whether the button got clicked, and did trigger the event.

Comment: Finally i made it working. I change the init line with initWithNibName and pass in the correct xib filename in. I thought init will automatically call the right xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly what you are doing but I think that you need to take a look at using modal view controllers or using a navigation controller. Apple documentation provides a lot of help for both.